# How is graph clustering performed?

Tags: clustering, partitioning

When we do graph partitioning or graph clustering how does one give the graph as input? Is it by means of an adjacency matrix? What if the graph is very large?

Answer (score 1):

There are [different data structures for the graph representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)#Representations). For example, when you have a very large sparse graph, you can use *adjacency list* instead of *adjacency matrix*. Note that, you need to choose the appropriate data structure when you want to implement the clustering algorithm yourself. If you want to use an available function in a library, the choice of the data structure is enforced by that special function.